# How to "block" calls?

Tags: iphone, call

How do we "block" calls such that no one is able to call through?

For example, I would not like anyone to call me for the next 60 minutes, but I do not wish to turn off the phone.

What's the best solution?

Comment: Just turn off the ringer?

Comment: @Nathan i actually don't understand what you mean by the ringer.. let alone be able to turn it off

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have four options.

1. Turn on Do Not Disturb and lock the screen (or configure it to block all calls whether the screen is locked or not on iOS 7)
2. Place the phone in AirPlane mode - this disables the cellular data, SMS and cellular calls as well as WiFi. You can turn on WiFi while in AirPlane mode to access data and still be undisturbed.
3. Use your carrier to start call forwarding. It will send your calls to another number (google voice is a nice place to send them if you don't have another appropriate line). On AT&T, you dial the following to start forwarding, call: ****21*1234567890#** - assuming your other number is **(123)456-7890**. To stop the forwarding, call **#21#**
4. Remove the sim. If you have another sim (same carrier or unlocked phone) that would in effect turn off your primary phone service without deactivating the phone.

Comment: i do not wish to disable the cellular data, sms and stuff like that. do you know what is our number for google voice? (and do we have to pay to use google voice?)

Comment: Google voice is free for most people in the US. You get your own number from them as a part of the sign up process.

Comment: i'm from singapore.. and i don't have a google voice. is there anyway i can simply block all calls or something?

Comment: If you don't want to turn off your phone and you don't want to put it in Airplane mode to disable the cell signal you're out of luck. The only other way is to turn the ringer volume all the way down.

Comment: You'll have to ask your carrier. We have exhausted the things you can control. (vibrate+ring sound, forwarding, airplane mode). The only other really bad option is to turn off call waiting and occupy the phone by calling another number and not hanging up for the hour.

Answer (score 1):

Ask you cellular carrier how to forward calls.  Then forward the calls to some other number (your office, an answering service, some phone that your cousin never picks up, etc.)

Comment: is forwarding really the only way to go about it? can't we simply like let it be killed or smt?

Comment: No.  There is no such option to be found on a stock OS iPhone.

Comment: is there an app that provide this functionality?

Comment: Check with you cell carrier for if they have an app.